# Can margins in PDF be modified without losing original quality?

Tags: pdf, dpi, print-to-pdf, margins, acrobat-pro-dc

AFAIK, the only way to modify margins is to print it with a larger page size and then crop the new file. But the DPI is significantly decreased while the file size is significantly increased, not to mention that the OCR layer and bookmarks are lost. This is understandable because it has to export the PDF to images then recombine them.

Is there a way to modify margins without having to print? If so, how to do that (not necessary in Acrobat Pro though)?

Comparing the original one with the printed one:
[image]
[image]

This is the screenshot when maximally zoom in the original file:
[image]

Comment: What kind of PDF are you dealing with? Is this a PDF that was created digitally from a document, or was it scanned and is basically an image?

Comment: @Zeff no that's not a duplicate. That question asks for how to increase margins **when printing**. This question asks for how to increase **without having to print**

Comment: @music2myear yes it's a scanned document. But you can zoom it for how much detail as you please without getting blurred

Comment: Those two statements are mutually exclusive. You may be able to zoom in as much as you like without losing fidelity, but a scanned image is not infinitely scalable without a loss of fidelity. That is also immaterial to your question, more or less. I'm not super familiar with Adobe Acrobat, but I'd guess they have a page layout section where you get to define the size of the image. The simplest method would be to screenshot the PDF and paste it into a new document and adjust the scaling there.

Comment: @music2myear I've added a screenshot in my post to aid what I mean. The only way I know to *increase* page size is to print it, decreasing can be done with crop tool. I think if we have to screenshot it, then it's more better to print it at the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase margins, first you have to ... crop it. Go to Tools > **Pages > Crop**, select random area on the file and double click it. In the Set Page Boxes dialog first you change the page size to a larger one, then set all crop margin to zero (the Margin Controls might be shaded after step 1, just change the option to a random one). Don't forget to apply to all before click OK.

[image]

Then you can now actually crop the page. Go to Tools >  **Print Production > Set Page Boxes**. The same dialog will open, but this time the old margins are shown to compare with the new margins before cropping.

FYI: [Adobe Support: Crop PDF pages](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/11/using/crop-pdf-pages.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Most PDF editors can do it. But keep in mind, printing to pdf is not considered to be a PDF editor.

A PDF editor actually opens an existing document for editing.

There are a few choices that come to mind, but please note, Software recommendations are considered off-topic, so I'm not going to recommend any of them, this is just so you have a reference as to what it is you would need to research to find a tool that works for you.

- Adobe Acrobat Pro (not the basic reader, but the version that can edit PDF's)
- Foxit Phantom PDF
- Adobe PhotoShop

Comment: As he tagged his post Adobe Acrobat, I assumed he had the full product, but it's probably reasonable to not assume that too.

Comment: @music2myear well, given that he also has print-to-pdf and another topic about printing to pdf, its more likely adobe-acrobat refers to the reader, because it used to be acrobat reader. And yes, in our line of work, assumptions are a really dangerous thing. :) But that said, I know photoshop can do this for sure, the other 2 should too, but its a bit more complicated to do it there.

Comment: Ok, so how to do this in Acrobat Pro? The only way I know is to print it

Comment: I don't actually own Acrobat Pro, but I have worked with Foxit Phantom PDF which is supposed to be the counter of Acrobat Pro. You can basically edit the document type from layout 1 to layout 2. Photoshop can really do anything with it, including cropping.

Comment: Can you give more details on how to do it in Foxit? Google result tells me to print the file too: https://help.foxitsoftware.com/kb/how-do-i-change-page-size-of-an-existing-pdf.php